# Can't solve "list out of range"

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, list

I'm using arcpy in ArcGIS 10.0. My code is supposed to test the intersection between all layer in a geodatabase by group of 2, and if so, erase one feature of each couple by the other depending on a reliability field. But I have an issue with stopping the listing of the list and I get the error "list index out of range".
Here is the way I do the job by couple of layer :

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.workspace = r'Z:\Documents\SIG\tests\agregation_auto\erase.gdb'
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() 
outFolder = r"Z:\Documents\SIG\tests\agregation_auto"
count = 0 #help select the a feature class
cnt = 1 #help select the b feature class
tList = len(fcList) #Count the number of elements in the list
for fc in fcList:
    if arcpy.Exists("temp"):
            desca = arcpy.Describe("temp")
            descb = arcpy.Describe(fcList[cnt])
            namea = desca.baseName # Get the name of the a feature to name the out_poly
            nameb = descb.baseName # Get the name of the b feature to name the out_poly
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, temp), "fca")
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, fcList[cnt]), "fcb")
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("fca","NEW_SELECTION")
            arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("fcb","INTERSECT","fca")

    else:    
            desca = arcpy.Describe(fcList[count])
            descb = arcpy.Describe(fcList[cnt])
            namea = desca.baseName # Get the name of the a feature to name the out_poly
            nameb = descb.baseName # Get the name of the b feature to name the out_poly
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, fcList[count]), "fca")
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, fcList[cnt]), "fcb")
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("fca","NEW_SELECTION")
            arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("fcb","INTERSECT","fca")

    if arcpy.Describe("fcb").FIDSet: #Check for selection
            rowa = arcpy.SearchCursor("fca")
            rowb = arcpy.SearchCursor("fcb")
    for row in rowa:
            fiabia = row.fiabilité #get the int value of reliability (all entities of a layer have the same)
    for rows in rowb:
            fiabib = rows.fiabilité
    if fiabia > fiabib: 
            out_poly = os.path.join(outFolder, nameb + "_er_" + namea + str(count) + "_" + str(cnt))
            tmp = arcpy.Erase_analysis("fcb","fca", out_poly)
    if fiabia < fiabib:
            out_poly = os.path.join(outFolder, namea + "_er_" + nameb + str(count) + "_" + str(cnt))
            tmp = arcpy.Erase_analysis("fcb","fca", out_poly)

    if count == tList - 1:
            break
    elif cnt == tList:
            count = count + 1
            cnt = count + 1
    else:
            cnt = cnt + 1



del rowa, rowb, row, rows, desca, descb, namea, nameb, fc, fcList
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("fca", "CLEAR_SELECTION")
arcpy.Delete_management("fca")
arcpy.Delete_management("fcb")
```

To help understanding the above, imagine the following list :

```
list = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

The loop will do the job for 0 with 1 first, then for 0 with 2, 0 with 3, 0 with 4.Then, 1 with 2, 2 with three, 3 with 4 and so on until count = 3 and cnt = 4 where I want to stop the process to avoid the out of range list.

Any idea ?

Comment: Should the if statement be indented one more level?  What line is giving you the error?

Comment: Yes it's a mistake when copying code on the forum. I'm correcting this right know.

Comment: Can you explain or further detail what are you trying to do? I am confused by your sentence: > My code is supposed to test the intersection between all layer in a geodatabase by group of 2, and if so, erase one feature of each couple by the other depending on a reliability field.

Comment: Yes, I know it's difficult to explain. My aim is to combine the best part of some features of a geodatabase in one feature class. A good layer has a reliability field value superior to a worse layer. To do this, I must erase the worst features by the better ones when there is intersection before combining layers. This script is supposed to do the erase but I didn't wrote this part of the code here because the error deals only with the list and its increment.

Comment: @Samy-DT , I just realized that your indentations are different in the top code you have four spaces while it's eight on the bottom. In addition, I would recommend you update your question to reflect your above comment.

Comment: @dassouki, I did the change and hope this help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work better with nested `for` loops based on the list length, instead of iterating through the entire list.

```
for count in range(tList-1):
    for cnt in range(tList):
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(os.path.join(workspace, fcList[count]),"fca")
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(os.path.join(workspace, fcList[cnt]), "fcb")
        #other code (test intersection, choose which one must be erased by the other)
```

Comment: it's ok for the list range problem. My code need still some corrections to do exactly what I want but I'll search more by myself before posting again.